# How to display second api response in data table in vuetify

Tags: django, vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js, response

My module

```
class module(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 package = models.ForeignKey(package,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null = True)
```

```
class package(models.Model):
package_name = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def list_modules(request):
    paginator = PageNumberPagination()
    paginator.page_size = 20
package=package.objects.filter(id=request.data['package']).order_by('id')
    module =module.objects.filter(active_flag = True,package_id=request.data['package'])
    paginate = paginator.paginate_queryset(module, request)
    serializer = ModulesSerializer(paginate, many=True)
    print(serializer.data)
    data = paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
    return data
```

Serializer.py

```
class ModulesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model=module
        fields=('id','name')
```

```
class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 class Meta:
        model = package
        fields=('id','name')
```

Vuetify

```
 Module(type,id){
       var data={"package":id}
       var url = this.page ? '/projects/list_modules?page='+this.page : '/home'
              this.$axios.$post(url,data,config).then(response => {
              if(response){
                  this.modules = response.results
                  
                  }
                  }).catch(e => {
              })
      },
```

```
getPackages(){
            var data={"portfolio":this.filter_portfolio}
            var url = this.page ? '/projects/list_packages?page='+this.page : '/home'
              this.$axios.$post(url,data,config).then(response => {
              if(response){
                  this.packages = response.results
                  }
                  }).catch(e => {
              })
      },
```

i am showing response from getPackages()like this in data table

```
  <v-data-table
<template v-slot:items="props">
               <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
```

I want to show Module() data  in same datatable

Can I append two api's response date into single data?

Comment: Sharing some code would be a first step. We have no context as of right now. Then, merging the 2 arrays of data could be a nice start regarding your table.

Comment: Shared Some code Pls give some solution

Comment: That code is not enough. Please put yourself in my position. How useful can those snippets be? We have some pieces of code to fetch data, alright. How the shape of the data looks? We have no idea. How is the data used? Same, we have no idea. We'll need more context, a [repro] could be useful actually.

Comment: sure I try to do more